# Converting a percent, to a decimal?...using for volume control

Tags: java, android

This seems BEYOND easy but I cant see to find a clear answer...

Say I have a string (volume) that has a percentage...(80, 50, etc), I want to get the number in DECIMAL format, and then use that to figure out the volume to set the phone at. I already get the maxVolume...so it's just getting the correct value that's killing me...

```
Integer theVolume=Integer.parseInt(volume);
double decimalNumber = theVolume/100;
int calc=(int) (maxVolume*decimalNumber);
mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,calc, 0);
```

The decimalNumber is only coming out as 0.0...no matter what number I give it...?

Comment: Don't use `Integer` instances.  Instead, use `int` primitives (but also see answers below).

Answer (score 6):

Try doing it like this:

```
double decimalNumber = theVolume / 100.0;
```

The `.0` at the end converts it to a decimal number.

edit: And for reference, it behaves like this because Java is trying to divide two integers (when using 100) so it tries to output the result as an integer.  The result is a fraction so Java rounds it down by default to the closest integer to that fraction (0 in this case) and then assigns that integer value to your double.  By instead using 100.0, you are telling Java to divide the integer by a double, which is then knows it can keep the fraction result and not round down.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the volume as a double

```
double theVolume=Double.parseDouble(volume);
double decimalNumber = theVolume/100;
int calc=(int) (maxVolume*decimalNumber);
mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,calc, 0);
```

Comment: How did you got the 'maxVolume'?

Comment: @zygimantus - The maxVolume is assumed to be set somewhere upstream. See the question.